# createElement to replace document.write

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace the below document.write with createElement.

```
document.write('<pt:core.html pt:tag="img" id="a" src="/abc.gif"/>');
```

As below -

```
document.createElement("a");
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = "<pt:core.html pt:tag='img' id='a' src='/abc.gif'/>";
var c= document.getElementById("a").value;
```

I am getting document.getElementbyId is null or not an object in the line 2(where we use .innerhtml ). Your inputs are appreciated. thanks.

Comment: 'a' has no id as shown, and anchors never have a value property

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an `<a>` element, not an element with an ID of `"a"`.

Furthermore, you don't need to use `document.getElementById()` here at all, you can instead assign your `document.createElement()` to a variable and reference that instead:

```
var elem = document.createElement('a');

elem.innerHTML = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.createElement("a");` creates an `<a>` element and then throws it away because you don't capture its return value.

`document.getElementById("a")` gets an element with `id="a"` from the document. Since it is returning `null`, there is no such element in the document.

You probably want something more like

```
var myAnchor = document.createElement("a");
myAnchor.innerHTML = ...
```

---

`"<pt:core.html pt:tag='img' id='a' src='/abc.gif'/>"`, however, is not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
var element = document.createElement("a");
element.innerHTML = "<pt:core.html pt:tag='img' id='a' src='/abc.gif'/>";
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById` can't find the element until you append it to the DOM. You need to do something like:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.innerHTML = "<pt:core.html pt:tag='img' id='a' src='/abc.gif'/>";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

After this, you can use `document.getElementById("a")`. But `document.getElementById("a").value` is not a useful thing to do. `.value` is only meaningful for user input elements, such as text boxes, `<select>` menus, and checkboxes.

Comment: what does this do - document.body.appendChild(a);. does this add the html tag to the body of the html.

Comment: Also, can you please explain the below - var aobj=document.all? document.all["a"] : document.getElementById?a: ""

Comment: Old versions of Internet Explorer don't have `getElementById`, they have an object called `document.all` that contains all the elements. So that code is designed to run with both old and new browsers.

Comment: thanks. document.body.appendChild(a); - does this add the html tag contained in id("a") to the body of the html doing the job of document.write ?

Comment: Yes, that's what it does.